# Why is that when I am inserting a USB, Ubuntu gives me a signal that it is inserted, but it doesn't show up on the taskbar, but appears in disks?

Tags: boot, usb, mysql, 23.10, dell-vostro

I am using a Dell Vostro 3590, Ubuntu Linux version 23.10. However, I am unable to install MySQL community server, MySQL connector which I require for a project I am working on. I tried installing VirtualBox to run Windows 11, however, that too didn't get installed. So I decided that I am going to reinstall Windows 11 once again on my Laptop.

I thought it would be a relatively simple procedure: Download installation tool on my USB, burn it, then enter boot menu and download from there. However, this resulted in a more problems. I had 2 USBs, one which stored Ubuntu and one which stored Windows. When I inserted them however, my Windows one was signalling that it has been inserted, but didn't show up anywhere. My Ubuntu USB became unmountable. So I purchased a new USB, installed windows 11 in it, burnt it using balenaEtcher. But when I opened my boot menu with the pendrive inserted, it didn't show up anywhere, and when I booted back into Ubuntu, and reinserted the USB once again, it didn't show-up on the taskbar, but showed up in disks, and became unusable.

My questions are:

1. What exactly happened to my USBs?
2. How do I now install Windows 11 on my PC now?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove Ubuntu and put Windows back on?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133533/how-to-remove-ubuntu-and-put-windows-back-on)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create a Windows bootable USB stick using Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/289559/how-can-i-create-a-windows-bootable-usb-stick-using-ubuntu)

Comment: Ubuntu (or a prior OS) is **not** involved if you're installing Windows; you need your machine *firmware* to recognize a USB contains a bootable OS & then boot that media instead of booting the installed OS (*ie. you don't want Ubuntu running*). How you do this varies on the machine itself & its firmware settings, with large variation in options (I have a device that requires it off, me to press & hold a key down then it'll turn on & ask if I want to boot external media; otherwise it won't). Writing windows ISO to media is best done on a windows machine (in my opinion as Microsoft say).

Comment: As for your USB; I gather you write the ISO incorrectly and not as the ISO was documented it should have been written (ISO is a vague term, ISO 9660 is used by PCs & even that one standard has a large number of formatted files; relating to music & CDs when they originally came out; not all ISO files are identical thus the instructions on writing them from ISO provider). You likely wrote it using a different method & thus thumb-drive needs to have new partition table & format before it's re-usable. USB flash drives are also low quality, made to cost, and can fail when written to; cheap is the +